# Powershell Grouping of csv import file

Tags: file, powershell, csv, import

Hopefully I'm just missing something that is simple...

I have a csv file similar to this :

```
Employee ID, Entry Date, Product Code,Amount Due
0001,20/11/2017,A001,10
0001,20/11/2017,Q003,13
0001,20/11/2017,H001,8
0002,20/11/2017,P003,12
0002,20/11/2017,A001,7
```

and what I want as an output is similar to this :

```
0001;<some header text>;200171120
A001;10
Q003;13
H001;8
0002;<some header text>;200171120
P003;12
A001;7
```

So that each detail section is grouped by the Employee ID it relates to

I have tried piping the group-object ("Employee ID") after using an import-csv ... but I can't get it to work correctly

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You mention that you've tried using `group-object` but don't show the code you've tried, it's best to show your code (even if it doesn't work) so that we know you've at least tried to solve this issue and aren't just expecting us to write all you code for you.

Comment: I understand - I did originally cut and paste my several attempts, but removed as it just confused the post a little (I didn't want elements of my code to be corrected if I was ultimately doing it the wrong way!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you need:

```
$CSV | Group-Object 'Employee ID' | ForEach-Object {

    $EntryDate = (Get-Date ($_.Group.'Entry Date' | Select -First 1) -F 'yyyyMMdd')

    "{0};<some header text>;{1}" -f $_.Name, $EntryDate

    ForEach ($Item in $_.Group) {
        "{0},{1}" -f $Item.'Product Code',$Item.'Amount Due'
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Uses `Group-Object` to group the results by Employee ID and then `ForEach-Object` to iterate through the collection.
- Gets the Entry date from the first entry in the group, converts it to a date object with `Get-Date` and then formats it as year/month/day (this part assumes you don't care if there are other/differing dates in the collection).
- Outputs the header string you wanted, using {0},{1} as placeholders for the variables passed via `-f` (there are multiple ways to do this but this seemed tidiest for your scenario).
- Uses `ForEach` to iterate through the `Group` property, which contains the grouped items. Again using string replacement to output the product code and amount due fields in the format you desired.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark - I'm going to try now (also - much appreciate the additional explanation!)

Comment: Hi Mark. I've tried this, and PowerShell is prompting me for Process[0]. I've added in a write-host $file to check it actually has the file in question, but can't seem to get past this ..... I'm probably missing something very obvious here

Comment: Did you maybe put the `{` after the `ForEach-Object` on a new line? Because you can't do that with `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: (bit before specifies the $files= get-childitem <myinputdir and file mask>)
    $csvfile=import-csv $file
    
    $csvfile | group-object "Report Submit Date" |
    ForEach-Object 
    {
    $EntryDate = (Get-Date ($_.Group.'Report Submit Date' | Select -First 1) -F 'yyyyMMdd')
    write-host "Entry Date : " $EntryDate
    "{0};<some header text>;{1}" -f $_.Name, $EntryDate
    ForEach ($Item in $_.Group) {
        "{0},{1}" -f $Item.'Employee ID',$Item.'Amount Due'
    }
}

Comment: Wow - response in under a minute, and the correct response - again, many thanks (edited - technically 2 minutes, but the point being it was very quick ;-)

Comment: This isn't your issue, but take out that `Write-Host` because you can't use `-f` on the string when you do that.

Comment: Taken out the Write-Host, thanks. One more thing, if that's ok, I would like to test the $item in the $_Group to omit the ones where a particular value is blank .... my attempt at if [code]($item.'Account Code' -ne '') { [/code]  comes up with an error - is there a way I can conditionally test these values?

Comment: Just in case this assists anyone - my typing must have been poor :     ForEach ($Item in $_.Group ) {
         if ($item.'Journal Account Code' -ne '')
            {
            "L;5;;0;0;{2},{0},{1}" -f $Item.'Employee ID',$Item.'Report Entry Description', $item.'Journal Account Code'
            }
    }   - This seemed to work

Comment: You would be best to ask a new question so you can properly clarify what you're trying to do and what you've tried :).

Comment: Not sure if this might probably be best as new question also, but do you know why running the script as you specified above behaves differently when called from the command line to in the ISE? It appears to lose the variable values when using write-output on {0},{1}" -f $Item.'Product Code',$Item.'Amount Due'?