# Powershell grouping - one out

Tags: powershell

This is a related question to one I raised a little while ago ([Powershell Grouping of csv import file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458505/powershell-grouping-of-csv-import-file))

But might be different enough to warrant a new question!

I have a csv file similar to this :

```
Employee ID, Entry Date, Product Code,Amount Due
0001,20/11/2017,A001,10
0001,20/11/2017,Q003,13
0001,20/11/2017,H001,8
0002,20/11/2017,P003,12
0002,20/11/2017,A001,7
```

When I run the following code (snippet here) :

```
$csvfile=import-csv $files
$csvfile | group-object "Employee ID" |
ForEach-Object {
$first_line="Y"
$EmployeeID = ($_.Group.'Employee ID' | Select -First 1) 
if ($_.Group.'Employee ID' -ne "Employee ID")
    {
    $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
    $DateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $date
    if ($first_line="Y") 
            {
            $Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Journal Net of Total Adjusted Reclaim Tax' -Sum).Sum 
            $TaxSum = (($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Report Entry Total Reclaim Adjusted Amount' -Sum).Sum /2)
            $SumMinusTax=$Sum - $TaxSum
            $datestr_report='{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $Item.'Batch Date'
            $myoutput="E;S4000;INV;;{3};{2};PLE;4;{4};{6};{2};{3};GB01NETBACS;Expenses;GBP;;DMG;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;{7};{9}" -f $_.Name, $EmployeeID , $Item.'Employee ID', $DateStr,  $Item.'Report Name', ";", $Item.'Report Submit Date', $SumMinusTax,$Item.'Branch',$TaxSum #";" $Sum #$date
            write-output $myoutput | out-file -filepath $outputfile -append -encoding ASCII 
            $first_line="N"
            }
```

The $EmployeeID variable only catches up next time round - so always out of step by one

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Shouldn't `if($first_line="Y")` be `if($first_line -eq "Y")`?

Comment: I've just changed it but sadly the situation is still the same - the EmployeeID is only picked up once the next EmployeeID is picked up

Comment: Do you mean that the Employee ID's are always out by 1 row?  You havent got one of the CSV's with a blank space at the top have you?

Comment: The first EmployeeID shows as blank, the second EmployeeID is the first one etc..(the csv input files are just lines and lines of data - no blanks at all). Thanks

Comment: Can you include the source data for this in _this_ question as well as the expected output? That way people don't have to jump around.

Comment: I don't understand why `$EmployeeID = ($_.Group.'Employee ID' | Select-Object -First 1)` isn't `$EmployeeID = $_.Name`.  I also don't understand what `if ($_.Group.'Employee ID' -ne "Employee ID")` is intended to do.

Comment: `$Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Journal Net of Total Adjusted Reclaim Tax' -Sum).Sum` That is super risky with large numbers of non-integer numbers.  Compare `(1..100 | % { 0.1 } | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum` to `[decimal]$x = 0; 1..100 | % { $x += 0.1 }; $x`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I'll modify my code (and also add some source data - once I've anonymised it - if that hasn't fixed the issue). Many thanks